# Dockerfile with pyenv command can only execute with root USER

Tags: linux, docker, pyenv

I have the following Dockerfile

```
.
.
.
RUN groupadd --gid $GROUP_ID $GROUP_NAME
RUN useradd --create-home --no-log-init --uid $USER_ID --gid $GROUP_ID $USER_NAME

USER ${USER_NAME}
ENV HOME ${HOME:-/home/${USER_NAME}}

RUN curl https://pyenv.run | bash
ENV PATH=$HOME/.pyenv/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

RUN pyenv install -v 3.10.2

RUN mkdir -p $HOME/.pip
COPY ./pip.conf $HOME/.pip/pip.conf
COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN echo 'eval "$(pyenv init --path)"' >> $HOME/.profile
RUN echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)" && eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"' >> $HOME/.bashrc

RUN . $HOME/.profile && pyenv local 3.10.2
RUN apt-get remove -y curl build-essential && \
    apt-get -y auto-remove && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm /tmp/python-build*.log && \
    rm /var/log/*.log
```

I have permission problems with running pyenv, I've seen this is the way to set it up: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-installer

If I change the dockerfile and add: `USER root` before the `RUN . $HOME/.profile && pyenv local 3.10.2` everything works as expected, but I don't get why I have permission denied:
`/home/zselter/.pyenv/libexec/pyenv-version-file-write: line 21: .python-version: Permission denied` in case I just run it with the user that was added to the group beforehand.

How could I make this work without involving the root user here?
Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You typically don't need a virtual environment in Docker at all, since the Python package installation in a Docker image is isolated from other images and Pythons.  Delete all of this, and `RUN pip install` to install packages into the "system" Python tree (but again, isolated to the one image you're building).

Comment: I want to run tests using `tox` to see if they pass for different python versions, for simplicity I'm just installing python3.10.2 above, but I actually have 3 python versions that should be installed in this container

Comment: Could you use a Dockerfile `ARG` to build three different images for the three different Python versions?

Comment: well, I will just add the `USER root` probably, it's not a blocker. I  just wanted to understand what's going on here. Thought I'm missing something, feels really weird that I have to do the user switch there.